# Why can't I boot after successfully booting ONCE post-upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, upgrade, uefi, dell

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 18.04 (an old install) and Ubuntu 20.04, newly upgraded from a *second* Ubuntu 18.04 (more recent).  The machine is a **Dell Precision M6700**

The upgrade went smoothly and the machine rebooted into the fresh upgraded Ubuntu 20.04.  Then, today, I came to log in (I leave the lid closed) and apparently entered a wrong password.  A minute or so passed before I could enter another password.  Wouldn't let me in.  Wouldn't let me even type a second password.  Hard shutdown and reboot.
No login at all now -- just this:

[image]

Not really sure what to do.  Not using UEFI (a lot of people insisting on this are also shackled to Windows, which I'm not).  BIOS Legacy ROMs enabled, security lax, trying to give the OS every opportunity for success without throwing security roadblocks in the way.  PTT (TPM or whatever Dell is calling it these days) is turned OFF per other recommendations.

I am trying to get the Vulkan development packages running.  I don't remember doing anything with nVidia drivers (it pulled over whatever I had working well under 18.04), but as an interstitial measure from root I removed all the nVidia stuff, expecting it would revert to Nouveau.

Any ideas?  TIA

Comment: I ended up copying off my /home, /etc, and /usr directories and performing a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: copy off your data and do a fresh clean install.

Reason: kernel version post-upgrade:
5.4.0-66
Kernel version post fresh install:
5.8.0-44

Old stuff holds you back.